# Asmedia 106x SATA Controller preventing boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, uefi, sata, delock

Recently I bought a [DeLOCK 89384 PCIe card](https://www.delock.de/produkte/G_89384/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en) with 10 SATA 6Gb/s ports.

However, after installing it, I'd get the message below, preventing the OS 
to boot and after a few seconds I'd get a reboot and it'd freeze in the UEFI screen.

> Asmedia 106x SATA Controller AHCI Mode
>   [...]
>   S.M.A.R.T. supported
>   Using PCIe Gen 2 x2
>   Can't find any device

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling the CMSs (Compatibility Support Module) in the UEFI options of my MoBo:

> Launch PXE OpROM Policy -> Do not launch
>
> Launch Storage OpROM Policy -> Do not launch

Although this may be specific to my hardware (ASRock A320M Pro4 with an AMD Ryzen Zen2), others MoBo should have similar option if anyone else is having the same problem with similar cards!